# Как вывести название программы в котором сейчас находится пользователь?

Tags: python

**Здравствуйте, форумчане.** *У меня появился вопрос, как вывести название программы в которой сейчас находится пользователь? У меня уже есть небольшой код. И он выводит все коректно, но как сделать что бы он выводил только одно, первое приложение? (См. Фото1.) Что бы вывелось только Spotify?. Помогите!*

[image: Как выглядит вывод.]

КОД:

```
import subprocess
 
 
cmd = 'powershell "gps | where {$_.MainWindowTitle } | select Description'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
        if line.rstrip():
        a = (line.decode().rstrip())
        print(a)

abc = input()
```

Comment: Ну можно просто добавить break после print(a)

Comment: Я добавил, но выводит просто Description и в принципе задача выполнена, все правильно. Но мне нужно что бы выводился не Description а приложение. Но за ответ все равно спасибо

Comment: А, description - это тоже вывод субпроцесса? Тогда можно сделать что-то вроде: `proc_output = [line.decode().rstrip() for line in proc.stdout if line.rstrip()]; for i in range(3): print(proc_output[i])`. Выглядит не очень, конечно, но работать будет. Хотя лучше, наверное, найти способ сделать то же самое, используя не посторонние скрипты, а питоновские библиотеки. Либо надо глянуть, что у вас за скрипт, может быть он может возвращать названия нормально, без шапки.

Comment: Хорошо. Я попробую, спасибо заранее.

Comment: Блин. Все работает. Все выводиться. Спасибо вам огромное!! Я все исправил. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Как пометить ваш ответ правильным, не знаете?